# Uniform converge by polynomials in $|z|=1$ implies existence of a holomorphic function in $\Bbb D$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f \in C(\partial \Bbb D)$, and a series of polynomials such that $P_n(Z) \rightarrow^{uniform} f$ on $\partial \Bbb D$.

Show that there exists a function $F$ such that $F|_{\partial \Bbb D}=f$ and $F \in H(\Bbb D) \cap C(\overline{\Bbb D})$.

I have two different ideas here: 1. Define $F$ using Cauchy's integral formula on $\partial \Bbb D$, and somehow show that it is holomorphic. 2. Prove the existence of $F$ by using Morera's theorem. I'm not sure how to pursue these ideas further. Any clues?

Comment: Use the maximum modulus principle to show that $P_n$ converges uniformly inside the disc too.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!